# How do I get a user reference in Microsoft Graph Groups API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

From the Group API and `/Conversations` endpoint you can get a list of conversations and when looking in the Groups App you can see the user with image.

But data returned from API doesn't have any good data to use for a user lookup.

I would expect an email address at least, not just the name which is far from unique. Is there a efficient way to get the user without traversing all the threads and posts?

Data from API:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('{id}')/threads",
    "value": [{
            "id": "{id}",
            "topic": "Test main thread",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-10-20T11:35:04Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Jonas Stensved"
            ],
            "preview": "{message preview content}",
            "isLocked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "{id}",
            "topic": "The new Test group is ready",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-10-13T10:33:03Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Test"
            ],
            "preview": "{message preview content}",
            "isLocked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

How a group in the Groups app looks:

[[image: Groups App on iOS]]

Answer (score 1):

It might help to break down the object hierarchy here:

1. `Group` - parent to a collection of Conversation resources
2. `Conversation` - parent to a collection of Thread resources
3. `Thread` - parent to to a collection of Post resources
4. `Post` - the actual content sent to the Group by a User

In order to see which `User` resources map into a given `Thread`, you need to drill down another level to find the `Post` resources contained within the Thread.

You can do this using the `$expand=posts` parameter to expand the `Posts` collection. You can also a `($select=from)` the `$expand` so you only return the properties you need to map back to the `User` resource.

So this query:

```
/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/threads?$expand=posts($select=from)
```

will provide you a `Thread` result like this:

```json
{
    "id": "{thread-id}",
    "topic": "New Training Plans",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-07-31T18:59:05Z",
    "uniqueSenders": [
        "HR Taskforce"
    ],
    "preview": "{thread-preview}",
    "isLocked": false,
    "posts@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('{group-id}')/threads('{thread-id}')/posts(from)",
    "posts": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CwAAABYAAADE9kXbLjqkSJUGeLzs6eumAAAAAA0/\"",
        "id": "{post-id}",
        "changeKey": "CwAAABYAAADE9kXbLjqkSJUGeLzs6eumAAAAAA0/",
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "HR Taskforce",
                "address": "HRTaskforce@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

You can try this yourself using [this Graph Explorer example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/threads?$expand=posts($select=from)&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com).

Comment: Yes of course that is possible but that would make the client slow. What if I have 10 000 users that are traversing the thread on every load?

Comment: The size of the payload could have an impact but you can mitigate that a bit by selecting the minimum number of fields necessary. You can always make a second call for additional detail if the user wants to drill deeper. Another option (and one I use a lot) is to cache the results on your server for a very short period. This eliminates have 500 simultaneous requests to your backend turn into 500 simultaneous calls to Graph. Having a 10-30 second cache can have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Yes, but I would still say that it somewhat surprising that you don't get any unique reference to the user. At least an email would be appreciated.

Still need to cache everything, long term, and use webhooks to update cache to be able to user the Graph API in any meaningful way.

Comment: There isn't a unique reference because a conversation by definition involves one or more users (otherwise they're literally just talking to themselves :-). If you're just looking for the person who initiated the conversation, you could limit this to just the first thread/post in the conversation.

Comment: Yeah, but email is at least more unique than name. Ideally we'd like to do a lookup in our AD to see if we have the user there with a corresponding email address and show som additional properties and fall back to showing just name and email if it is an external user. How do the O365 Groups app pull out the user image?

Answer (score 0):

You can get group members list and iterate over them. Depending on the size o the group this might require paging. You can find more information in the docs: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes of course, the question is more on how to do this in a good way. Not finding a workaround.